# Architecture: WPF vs Web based for LOB financial application portfolio

Tags: wpf, angularjs, web, architecture

I am creating a roadmap for building a portfolio of systems/tools that will be utilized by financial services clients as their end to end solution. I want to make a decision on whether to write the code in WPF or build a web based application using a framework such as Angular. I have a ton of experience in WPF but have 0 experiences in web based application development. In case I chose the web route, there will be a learning curve for me. Their will be 3 other developers and a UI designer who will work with me. I don't care about the one time development costs for getting the product to the market. I care about using the correct framework for the problem at hand

Following are the criteria for making this decision:

- At the height of my business I will have atmost 60 clients and each
  client will have atmost 10 users.
- The application needs to be highly responsive.
- The entire application will consume around 300MB of memory in the worst case.
- Clients don’t want a product that increases their hardware/maintenance costs dramatically.
- They want to be able  to work from home.
- The users will not use the application via tablet/smartphone.

My first thought was to build a web platform for this because anything I read/listen tells me that web is where the world is going. However, I have the following concerns

- It doesn’t seem like the web frameworks that are out there are at par with WPF. (In case you have not read, Microsoft recently came out with a roadmap for WPF to show that it’s not dead)
- None of the competitor’s products are web based. Most of the products in the market are 4-5 years old and back then web frameworks were much worse.
- Some of the competitors are distributing their WPF/Java based product via Citrix. This gives clients a choice between downloading the application on the desktop or using it via Citrix in which case the application isn’t installed locally and also gives them an option to work from home.

With my non-existent experience in web development architecture, it seems like the main reason to develop a web product is “because all the cool kids are doing it” and because “that’s where the world is heading”.

I would love to hear your thoughts and guidance on how to make this decision.

Comment: `work from home` - I don't see why this is a limitation for a WPF based app. the .Net Framework is already installed in most Win7 and 8 installs. Your application is going to WCF or WebAPI to some server backend anyways. I used to work for a company that delivered a WPF based SAAS software that auto-installed and then connected to a remote backend. It provided the ability to use the software remotely without all the stupid hassle of javascript and HTML.

Comment: Anyways, your question is off topic for StackOverflow, you might want to post in programmers.stackexchange instead.

Comment: @HighCore, thanks! Can you please elaborate more on "delivered a WPF based SAAS software that auto-installed and then connected to a remote backend". I don't quite get the architecture you describe.

Comment: It was actually a regular WPF app that connected to a remote web-service based backend via WCF. They used some of the ClickOnce APIs to auto-update the app whenever needed, and there was 'something' (I can't remember if it was another small app or what) that auto-installed the .Net Framework if needed. However the install base of the .Net Framework is huge, you probably don't even need that.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Playing devils advocate, the only concern in that model is that clients need to be willing to install 3rd party windows applications on their PCs. These apps will be memory intensive like i said and they might think that this will increase their hardware costs. (The clients are non IT)

Comment: "3rd party Windows applications" sounds a little strange to me. When you install Photoshop in your computer you're basically using "3rd party Windows applications". When someone buys a software from a vendor (like you), they basically agree that they're going to install it...

Comment: And regarding the hardware issue, I usually tell people that they have to choose between cheap and good. No way around that, anyways you can manage to reduce memory footprint by keeping your visual tree relatively clean and using no transparencies (see Windows 7 "Aero" versus Windows 8). You can achieve this in WPF, while still keeping a professional look and feel, using MahApps.Metro.

Answer (score 0):

I have also struggled with a similar problem. There are two factors I will consider which are taking use of the full computer power and the UX (User Experience). WPF is the best for very complex Financial applications which deals with multiple documents at the same time. In a web application, to make the UX simpler, you deal with one document at a time.